# Using a loaded image with a THREE.Texture

Tags: jquery, three.js, textures

I'm loading an image using jquery for use with a model in a Three.js scene that's a JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/neoRiley/jc8FX/8/)

The image loads fine and I can appendTo a div and see the image.  But when assigning it to the material as the map, nothing shows up - I must be missing a step here:

```
$.loadImage("http://www.rockonflash.com/webGL/three/checkerboard.jpg").done( $.proxy(createObject, this) );

function createObject(img)
{
    console.log("image loaded: " + (img == null));

    //var image1= $("#image1");
    //img.appendTo(img1);

    var geo = new THREE.TorusGeometry(1, .4, 8, 16);
    var map = new THREE.Texture(img);
    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
    { 
            map: map, 
            shading:THREE.SmoothShading 
    } );
    var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    obj.DrawAllAxis(3);
    scene.add(obj);
}
```